Rsyslog template adds unnecessary space
The template looks like this:
template(name="ceftmpl" type="list"){
  property(name="timegenerated")
  constant(value=" ")
  property(name="hostname")
  constant(value=" CEF:0|")
  property(name="$!cefprodvendor")
  constant(value="|")
  property(name="$!cefprodname")
  constant(value="|")
  property(name="$!cefprodversion")
  constant(value="|")
  property(name="syslogfacility")
  constant(value=".")
  property(name="syslogseverity")
  constant(value="|")
  property(name="syslogfacility-text")
  constant(value=".")
  property(name="syslogseverity-text")
  constant(value="|")
  property(name="$!cefsvrty")
  constant(value="|")
  property(name="$!cefext")
  constant(value="\n")
}

But the output log has a space after ':', like this:
CEF: 0
I've tried to separate into three constants like this:
constant(value=" CEF")
constant(value=":")
constant(value="0|")

But, the space is still there
